# Simulate rotating disc using skew transformation

Tags: 3d, html5-canvas, css-transforms

I'm attempting to simulate the animated rotation of a disc around a central point using skew, translate, and rotate transforms, like seen here:
[image: disc rotating around center]

In this animation (created in OpenSCAD) the viewport is translated [0, -100, 200], with a viewing angle of 30º off the X axis and viewing distance of 1000.

I'd like to be able to parameterize the viewing angle, distance, and transform, as well as the distance from the center of rotation.

I attempted unsuccessfully to create the effect here using HTML5 canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/fqbwnvm1/1/.

I only have access to `scale`, `skew`, `rotate`, and `translate` transformations in the environment where I'll be using this, so I cannot use the `perspective` transform.